# WiX missing 'Start In' property in desktop shortcut

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, wix3.8

I am working with WiX from last 5 month with no issues. Recently, i am in need to have "StartIn" property in App Desktop shortcut. By default, its empty.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/W8C6njgv) is my full Installer code.

I am working with below code:

```
<Component Id="myapplication.EXE" DiskId="1" Guid="*">
   <File Id="myapplication.EXE" Name="My Application.exe" 
         Source="D:\My Application\My Application.exe">
      <Shortcut Id="desktopShortcut" Directory="DesktopFolder" 
                Name="My Application" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR"
                Icon="DesktopIcon.exe" IconIndex="0" 
                Description="My Application Description" />
      <Shortcut Id="ExeShortcut" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" 
                Name="My Application" Icon="StartMenuIcon.exe" IconIndex="0" />
    </File>
</Component>
```

But didn't work.

I have also tried adding "Target" property:

```
<Shortcut Target= "INSTALLDIR" Id="desktopShortcut" Directory="DesktopFolder" 
          Name="Virtual Sim Center Beta" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR"
          Icon="DesktopIcon.exe" IconIndex="0" 
          Description="My Application Description"  />
```

but getting error message:

```
The Shortcut/@Target attribute cannot be specified when the Shortcut 
element is nested underneath a File element.
```

Answer (score 4):

This script bellow is working for my WIX:

```
    ....
    <!-- Desktop Menu -->
    <DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
      <Component Id="FooDesktopShortcutMenu" Guid="*">
        <Shortcut Id="FooApplicationDesktopShortcut"
                  Name="Foo Application"
                  Description="The Foo is Cool!"
                  Target="[#FooMainApp]"
                  WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"
                  Directory="DesktopFolder"/>
        <RemoveFolder Id="DesktopFolder" On="uninstall"/>
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Microsoft\FooApplication" 
                       Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>

    ....

    <!-- Tell Wix -->
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="FooSetup" Level="1">
      .....
      <ComponentRef Id="FooDesktopShortcutMenu"/>
      .....
    </Feature>
    .....
```

Comment: Sorry, Adiono. This didn't worked for me. I have edited my post & added my full code there.

Comment: I have posted my full wix script on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23334824/1586914. Maybe you can get some clue there?

Answer (score 2):

Glytzhkof is right and so is your WiX source - just put it under the Component.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It answers the question by pointing out that the shortcut tag is in the incorrect place and should be underneath the Component tag and not the File tag. I am not requesting clarification from anyone.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by @Adiono check whether the 'WorkingDirectory' folder actually contains the 'Target'.
The 'Start in' of my shortcut was blank even when both 'WorkingDirectory' and 'Target' had valid values, but the 'Target' was not present in the 'WorkingDirectory'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Wix set up to try this, but you can try to move the **Shortcut element** up to be nested under the **Component element** and not the **File element**. Then set the **WorkingFolder attribute**. Try something like [this](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/create_start_menu_shortcut.html).

Comment: I don't think there is any **WorkingFolder** attribute with Wix. Its **WorkingDirectory**, which i have already added in my code. But still no luck.