# Registry change upon installing application C#

Tags: c#, registry, installation

Just about to try and make an install package for an app for that first time with visual studio. I have a registry value that needs to be changed when the program is installed I need the program to start everytime the computer starts.

Is this a fairly trivial task? Could someone point me towards something to try and achieve this.

So far I just have the app with it's forms etc.

Comment: Are you using Visual studio installer package???

Comment: I've never used a program but if that is the normal way to do it then I'll be using that yes.

Comment: I think i may be running a little too far ahead. perhaps I need to just go ahead and give it a go first and see how I get on. :E Quite unsure what im dealing with though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same problem, I'm using [WIX](http://wixtoolset.org/) and follow the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052698/wix-how-to-register-application-to-start-when-windows-launches) Stackoverflow question. I'm also new on WIX, here's my full WIX working script if you might interest (tested on Windows XP & Windows 8.1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

<Product Id="*" 
       Name="FooSetup" Language="1033"
       Version="1.0.1.1" 
       Manufacturer="Foo Enterprise" 
       UpgradeCode="9235c293-2f08-4c2b-b7a5-69d01f5fca32">

    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />


    <!-- Step 1: Define the directory structure -->
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">

       <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="FooSetup" />
       </Directory>

       <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
          <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="Foo Application"/>
       </Directory>

       <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />

    </Directory>

    <!-- Step 2: Add files to your installer package & add autostart feature -->
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">

       <!-- The main executable file-->
       <Component Id="FooApplication" Guid="3F122E60-3745-4AEB-ADA3-B90DCB87E0BD">
          <File Id="FooMainApp" Source="$(var.Foo.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes"/>
       </Component>

       <!-- The main lib file-->
       <Component Id="FooLib" Guid="83BEDB02-C9F5-4A06-B3D5-0A4D61D6A99C">
          <File Id="FooFileLib" Source="$(var.Foo.Lib.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes"/>
       </Component>

       <!-- Register windows autostart registry -->
       <Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="45C7AC46-1101-4301-83E1-D24392283A60">
          <RegistryValue Type="string"
                   Name="FooStartup"
                   Value="[#FooMainApp]"
                   Root="HKLM"
                   Key="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
                   Action="write"/>
       </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>

    <!-- Step 3: Add the shortcut to your installer package -->

    <!-- Start Menu -->
    <DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
       <Component Id="FooShortcutMenu" Guid="3874D005-4E1C-4C0E-9CEA-8CD8D5442B60">
          <Shortcut Id="FooApplicationStartMenuShortcut"
              Name="Foo Application"
              Description="The Foo is Cool!"
              Target="[#FooMainApp]"
              WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"/>
          <RemoveFolder Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall"/>
          <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Microsoft\FooApplication" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
       </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>

    <!-- Desktop Menu -->
    <DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
       <Component Id="FooDesktopShortcutMenu" Guid="D4D0A2ED-C0DB-4524-AC53-D30F904DB846">
          <Shortcut Id="FooApplicationDesktopShortcut"
              Name="Foo Application"
              Description="The Foo is Cool!"
              Target="[#FooMainApp]"
              WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"
              Directory="DesktopFolder"/>
          <RemoveFolder Id="DesktopFolder" On="uninstall"/>
          <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Microsoft\FooApplication" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
       </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>

    <!-- Tell Wix -->
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="FooSetup" Level="1">
       <ComponentRef Id="FooApplication" />
       <ComponentRef Id="FooLib" />
       <ComponentRef Id="FooShortcutMenu"/>
       <ComponentRef Id="FooDesktopShortcutMenu"/>
       <ComponentRef Id="RegistryEntries" />
    </Feature>
</Product>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Thanks @Adiono I'm going to give that a try, I think this alllows me to understand a little more of whats going in the Product.wxs file.

Comment: I'm getting an error on <!-- The main lib file--> section. I don't really understand this bit from your code. When I call it TheNameofmyApp and replace FooFileLib and var.MyAppName.Lib it produces an error "Undefined preprocessor variable.

Comment: I ended up removing the lib bit, I don't think I had a main lib file.

Comment: You're welcome @Jagga. The <-- ...file --> sections is depends on the project that you want to put (reference) in the setup. In my app I have 2 projects referenced to the wix setup project which are Foo as the main app (windows form app) and Foo.Lib (class library) for main app.

Answer (score 0):

It depends the tool you used to create the install package, generally you need to add a String Value under

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run     or
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

like "AppName" : "AppPath"
You also can achieve this by add the regstry in your code.